# I want to print success when user enter country name that exists in database and last letter of last country equals first letter of next country,

Tags: java, sql

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;  
class driver{  
public static void main(String args[]){  

while(true)
{
    try{  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/countries","root","");  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from countries"); 

        int count = 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What county");

String info = scan.next();

{

while(rs.next() )
{
    if(rs.getString("name").charAt(rs.getString("name").length() -1) == info.charAt(0) && rs.getString("name").equalsIgnoreCase((info)))
    {

System.out.println("success" + rs.getString("name"));
}




}

}

}
catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);
}  

}
}
}
```

My code obove connects to a database with all country names.  My game prints success when the last letter of the country given last equals the first letter of the country given next turn.  For example I type Canada, next input is Angola ect ...

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Why am I not getting a success reply?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the data, for both last character of "last country", and if the input data is a country, using the same row from the resultset.

Also, I wouldn't do it this way. You are fetching the whole table from database to where your application is running, just to compare it to user input one by one. You should do it with SQL.

Also, what is the definition of "last country"? In your code last country is all available countries in the table. If this is some kind of word association game, you need to store the last country inputted by user.